# angular component elements not always stylable in ie11

Tags: css, angular, internet-explorer-11

when I create a component `ng g c my-component`, the content is rendering fine in ie11 once I turn on the polyfills. However, that component breaks the CSS, refusing to be styled -- in particular, it refuses to take any height, regardless of contents. Debugging, at first I thought that it refuses a background color (which I use to identify blocks in ie since there is no highlight-on-hover), but when I add an explicit height suddenly the background color renders.

example (inside of `app-my-component`):

```
<article class="my routable component">
  <app-child-component></app-child-component>
  <footer>should be under the inner component content</footer>
</article>
```

inside app-child-component:

```
<!-- this section will never have a height -->
<section class="child component">
  <app-inner-component></app-inner-component>
</section>
```

inside app-inner-component:

```
<!-- this section naturally will have height after the async returns results -->
<section class="inner component">
  <div *ngFor="const item in asyncResultItems">hi mom!</div>
</section>
```

The footer text will render *on top of* the app-inner component's content.
I would prefer the footer text to follow -- basically, IE11 should treat app-* elements like divs, but it seems to refuse to count them when giving a height at all (styles *inside* work just fine, though).

What can be done about that (simply wrapping the component in a containing div also does not work, by itself)?

full example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhmded

Note, thanks to amazing help, I have diagnosed the problem (I added more and more of the differences between the minimum example and my actual code til I reproduced it). **Flex column** is breaking on the child component.

Comment: I'm afraid there is not enough information here to determine the problem.  This stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u23wd8) works just fine if I use the snippets you've posted.  Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/4dT49FI

Comment: your example was most kind, thank you. I am able to see now my problem `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhmded`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE11 does not properly support flexbox.  As you can see on https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox there are a number of known issues.  It is also very sensitive to syntax.  If I change your `flex: 1` rules to `flex: 1 1 auto` then it seems to work correctly for me at least.